Help me verify this solution on finding the flux of a 3d vector field
The Problem: Find the flux of a vector field $\vec{F} = 5\vec{i} - (y+3)\vec{j} + 2\vec{k}$ through the outer side of surface $\sigma: 2x+3y+5z=30$ bounded by coordinate planes.

My friend has a solution they would like to verify. They feel like it's not right, and I don't see anything wrong in it.


If you put some effort into cleaning it up into a presentable form instead a confused mess of unexplained calculations, you might actually attract replies.
